# Export .bag to .jpeg / .mp4 tutorial not outputting anything

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert a .bag file to .mp4 by following this tutorial: [How to export image and video data from a bag file](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data)

I did the following steps:

1. Ran: `roscd image_view && rosmake image_view && sudo apt-get install mjpegtools`
2. Created an `export.launch` file containing the code from the tutorial (file placed in `/opt/ros/melodic/share/image_view`)
3. Placed `test.bag` in `/opt/ros/melodic/share/image_view`
4. Ran `roslaunch export.launch`

After running the command `roslaunch export.launch`, there are no .jpeg files in the `~/.ros` directory like the tutorial says there should be.

The output of the `roslaunch` command is:

```
ThinkCentre-M90n-1:/opt/ros/melodic/share/image_view $ roslaunch export.launch
... logging to /home/max/.ros/log/801ba47c-f76e-11ea-b576-4074e0bec8b4/roslaunch-max-ThinkCentre-M90n-1-12751.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://max-ThinkCentre-M90n-1:33177/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.9

NODES
  /
    extract (image_view/extract_images)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [12761]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 801ba47c-f76e-11ea-b576-4074e0bec8b4
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [12774]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rosbag-2]: started with pid [12780]
process[extract-3]: started with pid [12782]
[ INFO] [1600186456.400606637]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
================================================================================REQUIRED process [rosbag-2] has died!
process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/max/.ros/log/801ba47c-f76e-11ea-b576-4074e0bec8b4/rosbag-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[extract-3] killing on exit
[rosbag-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

The log file contains:

```
[ INFO] [1600186456.311782786]: Opening /opt/ros/melodic/share/image_view/test_mask.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
 [RUNNING]  Bag Time:     34.406766   Duration: 34.406766 / 34.439933               6456.59 
Done.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? I am new to ROS (using melodic), am just using it to try to convert a .bag file I recorded on an Intel Realsense camera to .mp4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361625/export-.bag-to-.jpeg-/-.mp4-tutorial-not-outputting-anything/) by [mhudne11](https://answers.ros.org/users/59493/mhudne11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there are several problems here:

1. The contents of this tutorial are *incredibly* old. The `rosmake` command hasn't been used since before kinetic, which will be EOL next year.
2. You should be creating your files in a ROS workspace in your home directory instead of trying to make changes to `/opt/ros` which is where binary packages are installed. See [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces) for more information about workspaces.
3. For some reason, the launch file assumes that your rosbag will be in `/opt/ros` as well. For the reasons stated in 2, you should have it elsewhere (like your workspace) and replace the path `$(find image_view)/test.bag` with the full path to the rosbag.
4. Based on the code in `image_view/extract_images`, the node will drop the images in the folder in which you run the launch file, not `~/.ros`. This is why it is important to run the launch file somewhere that your user has write access to (like your home folder).

You should install the `image_view` package instead of building it from source. There is no need to build it from source as binaries exist for all current ROS versions. If you're using Ubuntu, the package name is `ros-melodic-image-view`. Once it's installed, source `/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` and your launch file should work.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhudne11](https://answers.ros.org/users/59493/mhudne11/) on 2020-09-16**:
Thank you for the clear explanation. By installing `image_view`, sourcing that bash file and using a different workspace, it worked! I also realized that I had to replace the topic in `export.launch`, i was able to find a list of topics in the .bag file with `rostopic -b test_mask.bag`. There were many topics, but the one which sounded the most reasonable was `/device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data`.

The only issue I have now is the extracted number of frames was much less than expected (it output 295 when the .bag file contains ~1100). Do you know what might cause it to skip frames?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-09-16**:
Sorry, not sure what's causing that. Might want to check the rate at which the images are being produced from the bag file and how the saver is imlemented in `extract_images`.